# Splicing with THHN or NM-B inside of a new panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I'm planning to upgrade my 100A (12 spaces) panel to a 42 spaces 200A panel. I might have to extend some conductors inside the panel to reach the new breakers. Can I use individual conductors pulled from a NM-B cable to extend the hot/neutral/ground or should I use THHN? I have some leftover 10 and 12 gauge THHN, can I use that for example to extend the black on a 15A 14 gauge circuit, but leave the neutral 14 gauge? I would use Wago lever-nuts for the connections?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming that "either type is OK", which I *think* is the case (based on "that's OK for pigtails in a junction box", which may or may not be the case for a panel box), I would *not* mix and match wire sizes. If you have a mix, the inspector might (a) consider that not good workmanship (debatable, but could cause troubles) and/or (b) start poking around at every little detail because while legitimate (any place you can use 14, you can use 12 instead) mixing within a single circuit section (i.e., hot vs. neutral for one circuit in the panel box) looks *odd*.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact good point that it is OK for pigtails in a junction box, so it should be OK in a panel. Hadn't thought of it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically speaking, unmarked Romex wire is problematic because it has no markings on the individual conductors, making it "mystery meat" as ThreePhaseEel says.

However, I don't see an AHJ flagging you.  They know the score.

A word on procurement: Most consumers suffer in a "big-box rut" where they can only contemplate buying from big-box stores.  At real hardware stores or lumberyards, you will find many of them cheerfully sell wire by-the-foot including THHN wire, for considerably less than the small-spool prices at the box store.  (who used to sell wire by-the-foot until they realized small spools are obscenely lucrative).

Comment: My local HD sells "bulk" (i.e. off a big spool) THHN up to I think 8 gauge—maybe 6—by the foot.  No idea if their pricing is competitive with specialty electrical shops.

Comment: Yes, i was thinking about the fact that you can't use individual Romex conductors without the sheathing in conduit, because it is unmarked. But it sounds like it won't be an issue for a few short pieces in a panel.